# MassTransit Send Command with Interface Property

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit in my project and I am trying to send a command that has an interface property inside. I set the **Document** property in the **ICreateDocumentCommand** command to an **InventoryList**. It sends it without any problems. But when I receive it I get a **GreenPipes.DynamicInternal.Common.Models.IDocument** on the receiving end.

**And that IDocument holds only the properties of the type Document, it has no properties from the InventoryList Class.** Basically I am only transferring the Id, AuthorId and DateCreated without the WarehouseId and all the rest properties from InventoryList.

All of my classes are really inside Common.Models but I would prefer getting Common.Models.InventoryList instead of IDocument.

**That's how I send the command:**

```
await endPoint.Send<ICreateDocumentCommand>(new
{
    CorrelationId = //from outside
    SocketId = //from outside
    UserName = //from outside
    UserId = //from outside
    Document = //from outside (InventoryList)
});
```

**Here is the command definition:**

```
public interface ICommand
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    Guid SocketId { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
    Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Command : ICommand
{        
    public Command() {}

    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public Guid SocketId { get; set; } 
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public interface ICreateDocumentCommand : ICommand
{
    IDocument Document { get; set; }
}

public class  CreateDocumentCommand : Command, ICreateDocumentCommand
{
    public CreateDocumentCommand() {}

    public IDocument Document { get; set; }
}
```

**That was the command, now the IDocument:**

```
public interface IDocument
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class Document : IDocument
{
    public Document() {}

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

**Finally the InventoryList:**

```
public class InventoryList : Document
{
    public InventoryList()  {}

    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public string Copmany { get; set; }
    public Guid ResponsiblePersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid FirstCommissionMemberId { get; set; } 
    public Guid SecondCommissionMemberId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Struggling with a similar issue (in addition to complete types the delivered model has one property that is interface and instead of getting the implementing object (`SimpleValueCollection`) set for that property, I get `GreenPipes.DynamicInternal.OurNameSpace.IValueCollection`).

Comment: @Gonnagle, Please have a look at my comment here. It might solve the problem.

Comment: @Gonnagle nope, I haven't found any suitable solution, just created commands for every concrete class.

Answer (score -1):

This is  more a basic serialization issue. When you deserialize **ICreateDocumentCommand** it will deserialise **IDocument** as an **IDocument** -- that is, an interface. This is because there's no way to know from the interface definition which concrete type should be hiding behind the **IDocument**.

Here is a decent blog post detailing the problem and a solution: http://appetere.com/post/serializing-interfaces-with-jsonnet.

1. You can also add custom serializer on on your consumer to deserialize it properly which would cause a lot of hassle.
2. If you can use abstract class instead of interface, then there is a easy solution for this. Just redesign you code like this:

   ```
   public class CreateDocumentCommand : Command, ICreateDocumentCommand
   {
        public CreateDocumentCommand()
        {

        }

        [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
        public DocumentBase Document { get; set; }
   }

   public abstract class DocumentBase
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

       public abstract DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
   }
    public class Document : DocumentBase
   {
       public override DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
   }
   ```